# Haskell Recursion with Chars

Tags: string, haskell, recursion

Write a recursive Haskell function

```
makeString :: Int -> Char -> Char -> String
```

such that `makeString n ch1 ch2` returns a string as follows:

- When n is positive, the string has length 3n-2 and contains n copies
  of ch1, each copy separated by two copies of ch2.
- When n is less than or equal to zero, the string is the empty string.

For example, the function has the following behavior:

```
Main > makeString 5 'a' '!'
"a!!a!!a!!a!!a"
Main > makeString 1 'a' '!'
"a"
Main > makeString 10 '6' '#'
"6##6##6##6##6##6##6##6##6##6"
```

So far I have:

```
makeString :: Int -> Char -> Char -> String
makeString n ch1 ch2
           |n <= 0        = [ ]
           |otherwise     = ch1: makeString(3*n-2)(ch2)(ch1)

Main> makeString 5 'a' '!'
"a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a!a"
```

Comment: Why are you calling your function recursively with `n = 3*n-2`? What was the purpose of that?

Comment: I was told to use 3n-2 so I thought that was what was meant.

Comment: Honestly I just tried anything because it just did not make sense.

Comment: Somewhat fixed code to look better but still not there.                           
series :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
series n item
  | n <= 0    = []
  | otherwise = item : series (n-1) item


doubleCount :: Int -> [[Int]]
doubleCount n
            |n <= 0        = [ ]
            |otherwise     = helper 1
           where
            helper :: Int -> [[Int]]
            helper i
                   |i > n      = [ ]
                   |otherwise  = (series i n) : helper(i+1)

Comment: gives me: *Main> doubleCount 6
[[6],[6,6],[6,6,6],[6,6,6,6],[6,6,6,6,6],[6,6,6,6,6,6]]

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty implementation

```
module Test where

merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : y : merge xs ys

makeString :: Int -> Char -> Char -> String
makeString 0 _ _ = []
makeString n ch1 ch2 = take ((3 * n) - 2) $ merge (replicate (3 * n) ch1) (replicate (3 * n) ch2)
```

The `replicate` creates long enough lists for `merge` to do its work. Works for all positive `n`s

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
makeString :: Int -> Char -> Char -> String
makeString n ch1 ch2
  | n <= 0 = ""
  | n == 1 = [ch1]
  | otherwise = [ch1, ch2, ch2] ++ makeString (n-1) ch1 ch2
```